# React / Redux components rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hi I have been using React / Redux for may App. I have to render multiple input fields dynamically. The problem which I am facing right now is...

So suppose, the form already have 2 input fields, and I want 5 input fields total, I will simply render these with the help of a loop with 5 repetitions. the problem is react renders 3 new fields and keeps 2 old at top. But I need fresh 5 fields. Is there a way to force react to remove old fields first and then render 5 new fields.

Comment: code ? refactor your input into its own component and then render it with a loop ?

Comment: React will make the minimum number of DOM changes to achieve what you ask for. It's difficult to say this is the best way without seeing your code, but I imagine if you drop all the fields (down to zero) and then build them back up, you should end up with 5 fresh ones.

Comment: can you show an example of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the key attribute. If you give the components new keys each render, then the fields will be recreated

A small example is below. I used Math.and() to generate unique keys. Of course, better to use shortid or similar

https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/shortid

```
class InputRenderer extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      inputsCount: 3
    }
  }

  handleInputsCountChange = (newCount) => {
    this.setState({
      inputsCount: newCount
    })
  }

  renderInputs = () => {
    const inputs = []
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.inputsCount; i++) {
      inputs.push(<input key={i + Math.random()} />)
    }
    return inputs
  }

  render = () =>
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => this.handleInputsCountChange(3)}>3</button>
      <button onClick={() => this.handleInputsCountChange(5)}>5</button>
      {this.renderInputs()}
    </div>
}
```